# How to speed up insert performance in CockroachDB

Tags: cockroachdb

Is there a way to optimize the insertion of a lot of data into an empty CockroachDB table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To optimize inserting data into CockroachDB tables, there are a few pieces of guidance:

- Create the table without any secondary indexes, insert your data, and then add any secondary indexes you want.
- Insert 500 rows per `INSERT` statement. That number might vary a bit depending on the size of your rows, but is a good guideline to optimize the speed at which you can write data.
- Use [the `IMPORT` statement](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/import.html) to bulk import CSV files into a single table. This is the fastest way to get data into CockroachDB.

If you're moving from PostgreSQL to CockroachDB, you can also use `pg_dump` to create a `COPY` statement, which CockroachDB is optimized to ingest. It's a slightly more involved process, but you can find the details about how to do it in [CockroachDB's import documentation](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/import-data.html).

Comment: Using batches of 1000 rows, still seeing about 1-2 transaction per second. I do have secondary indexes, but is this the expected speed? (3 nodes)